# mock catch exception using PhpUnit

Tags: phpunit

recently i see some issue on my projects, a found that there is some exception that i forget to catch them! this is my code:

```
try {
    $this->user = $invoiceEvent->user;

    $this->invoice = $invoiceEvent->invoice;

    if ($this->user->email) {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }
}catch (Swift_RfcComplianceException $e) {

}
```

by using this try/catch my problem is solved, this is my test, and is green!, who can i assert the exception is catch?

```
 /**
 * @test
 */
public function it_should_Not_provide_exception_when_mailFromAddress_is_not_set()
{

    $invoice = $this->makeInvoice();
    $user = $this->makeUser();
    $mail = app('Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer');

    (new SendInvoiceToUser($mail))->handle(new InvoiceCreated($invoice, $user)); 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally using this way i assert the exception catch an my method in this situation return null that is exactly what i except.

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function it_should_Not_provide_exception_when_mailFromAddress_is_not_set()
{

    $invoice = $this->makeInvoice();
    $user = $this->makeUser();
    $mail = app('Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer');


    $mocked = $this->getMockBuilder(SendInvoiceToUser::class)
        ->setConstructorArgs([$mail])
        ->setMethods(null)
        ->getMock();

    $this->assertNull($mocked->handle(new InvoiceCreated($invoice, $user)));
}
```

- by pass null to  ->setMethods(null) the mocke object run the actual code contained within the method when called,